# Optimizing a recursive path finding algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, pathfinding

On input i get width and height of matrix, string of text and another string of finalText I want to reach. The characters of the first string are assigned to matrix. My goal is to find shortest way to create finalText from characters in matrix, starting at position (0,0), and return number of steps.

So I create a dictionary of all coordinates and characters from finalText.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, char> coords = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, char>();
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
   if (finalText.Contains(matrix[j, i]))
    coords.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(j, i), matrix[j, i]);
  }
}
```

And then use it in my function. I basically calculate steps in all possible paths and then return the shortest one.

```
static int ShortestPath(char[,] matrix, string str, int x, int y, int steps, Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,char> coords)
        {
            if (str.Length == 0)
            {
                return steps;
            }

            else
            {
                List<int> l = new List<int>();

                foreach (var item in coords)
                {
                    if (item.Value == str[0])
                        l.Add(ShortestPath(matrix, str.Substring(1), item.Key.Item1, item.Key.Item2,
                            steps + (Math.Abs(x - item.Key.Item1) + Math.Abs(y - item.Key.Item2)), coords));
                }
                
                int min = l[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < l.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (l[i] < min)
                        min = l[i];
                }
                return min;
            }
        }
```

The algorithm is working, but for bigger matrices it's too slow and I have no idea how to optimize it or do it otherwise.

Comment: Can you provide the entire project? Something like a GitHub repository or similar.

Comment: In the code presented, I can't discern *width and height of matrix, string of text and another string of finalText* from the introduction.

Comment: Can you try to expand the problem statement a bit more? I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do. I think you'll want to use [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for the best performance

Comment: I think you would have a lot more useful answers if you take the time to explain what you want to achieve. I don´t know if I understand correctly, but you have a matrix with a bunch of letters and you want to know how many operations does it takes to end with a desired string. However it is not clear whether you should always start at the same point (0,0), or a diagonal step costs the same as a vertical or horizontal one. As a minor review, consider renaming your vars to reflect what they do. I also think your problem is in the recursive step

Comment: @EnriqueCastaneda Oh, i forgot, i can move only vertically or horizontally. Also, starting at (0,0) means that #steps to achieve first character in string is calculated by |0-x| + |0-y|. (as i pass zeros to the function)

Comment: (Cross-post from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940616/optimizing-a-recursive-path-finding-algorithm#comment127129460_71940616).)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a C# programmer, so I don't quite understand your algorithm. However, there is couple of things I could tell you:

**Advice 1: Unnecessary `else`**

You have:

```
{
    if (str.Length == 0)
    {
        return steps;
    }

    else
    {
        List<int> l = new List<int>();
        ...
    }
}
```

You could write simply:

```
{
    if (str.Length == 0)
    {
        return steps;
    }

    List<int> l = new List<int>();
    ...
}
```

**Advice 2: Use `min` or similar**

Instead of

```
int min = l[0];
for (int i = 1; i < l.Count; i++)
{
    if (l[i] < min)
        min = l[i];
}
```

you could write

```
int min = l[0];
for (int i = 1; i < l.Count; i++) 
{
    min = Math.Min(min, l[i]);
}
```

(See [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=net-6.0).)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I miss comments.

I don't see `matrix` used in `ShortestPath()`.

Just returning the minimum, don't build the `List<int> l` in the first place.

---

Having a look at *shortest path* algorithms in general and [Dijkstra's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275900/optimizing-a-recursive-path-finding-algorithm/275934#comment546442_275900)  in particular is solid advice.

Things I might consider:

- create [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s for both `finalText` and the entire matrix (say, `available`)
- If there is any character occurring in `finalText` but missing from `available` (assuming characters/cells/elements may be used more than once - *occurring more frequently* otherwise), there's no solution
- the problem splits into problems that can be handled independently at any string consisting of characters occurring just once: solitaires
- remove all prefixes and suffixes of solitaires
- using *sum norm* / *taxicab distance*, for any *start* and *target*, intermediate points increase distance only when introducing the need to "turn back" (lying outside the rectangle defined by *start* and *target* in case of just one intermediate).

Comment: Nice point about no list.

Comment: It may be a good idea generally to process characters required by `finalText` by increasing frequency in the matrix.